# How do I share an individual Google Chrome Bookmarks folder with someone else?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How do I share an individual Google Chrome Bookmarks folder with someone else?

I have a folder full of articles I wish to send to someone one, without opening them up individually and sending each one.

Comment: Export your Bookmarks as HTML using Chrome's built-in exporter, open the HTML file and remove anything you don't want them to have and tell them to import it.

Comment: Heads up folks, it looks like the share feature in bookmark manager is gone as of the moment. I relied on it pretty regularly, so editing your html file might be the best method for the time being.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a third-party browser extension that adds this functionality to the browser, such as [Bookmark Llama](https://www.bookmarkllama.com?utm_source=superuser). This would allow you to selectively share bookmarks without importing and exporting them whenever they change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1115977)

Answer (score 9):

Two options (easiest first):

1. You can use the new [Bookmark Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/idakfiahffeejfhghndaboolmmhbnepn) extension, which replaces the built in one. You can then go to the folder you want to share (via the extension), and click `Share this folder` at the top right of the page
2. You can use the default bookmark manager and `export bookmarks to html` and manually remove the bookmarks that aren't in the folder you want to share.

Comment: I think google removed 'Share this folder' button in the latest version.

Comment: Hmmm that's annoying :( I'll see if I can find anything new but maybe the manual method is the only way forward atm...

Comment: I don't think the Bookmark Manager has the `Share this Folder` option anymore (at least I could not find it)

Comment: The Share option is gone, but at least the Bookmark Manager extension still has the export option (unlike the built in one). So #2 still works

Comment: I could not see the export feature anymore... is it gone?

Comment: @Arninja it should still be there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OpzN.png under the menu with 3 dots on the right hand side

Comment: Couldn't find the "Share this folder" option either, the screenshot didn't help, I didn't find the menu either. Recording a short video would be more useful. (Using Brave browser)

Answer (score 5):

It's dead simple to share a folder of Chrome bookmarks. Open Chrome's standard bookmark manager, open the specific folder or sub-folder whose contents you want to share, then in the right-hand pane just copy the icons of the web pages. Then paste into an email (this action will yield a list of URLs, not icons) and send.

Comment: this does not work if there is a hierarchy of folders and bookmark

Comment: although helpful, this isn't really "sharing" in the sense that they can't see the latest.

Comment: And it doesn't allow importing easily either.

Comment: (It doesn't work on edge)

Answer (score 3):

I used [Export Selective Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-selective-bookmark/ahgbiciilcpclcekhegbhofljoolnfei?hl=fr) extension, which does only that. (and doesn't ask for funky permissions)

Note that upon first use, it might display "can't fetch bookmarks" but it will eventually succeed given a bit of time. (as stated in the reviews)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, man!